# Popup form when entering website asking for e-mail address?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plugin or some sort of script where a simple pop-up comes up and asks for a visitors e-mail for a newsletter. The client is stressing it be a pop-up of some sort. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side-note, also consider suggesting an alternative method of collecting visitors data to your client. Those popups are really a pain for the user and are generally not recommended.

Comment: I would advise that you visit Stack Overflow and search for questions such as "javascript lightbox/popup". I would also strongly recommend against doing this. It will drive users away and damage your clients reputation, aside from being quite annoying.

Comment: There are ton of popup solutions for WordPress. Here is a [popup optin form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailoptin/)  i always use as well Popup maker plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely write that by Javascript, using a jQUery lightbox plugin, follow these step:

- add a "hidden" link to your page, when its "click" event is fired, that will pops your form (we'll make the fake click event later)
- create HTML markup for the popup form
- enqueue jQuery lightbox plugin (you may choose Colorbox, Thickbox, PrettyPhoto, etc.)
- enqueue jQuery cookie plugin (for prevent the popup on every page load, we just want to show it when user first go to the page)
- enqueue your custom script

In the custom script, you should:

- make a fake click event to your "hidden" link, like this: `$('#popup-link').click();`
- set a cookie for your user, maybe 1 day

The Popup Dominition is a bit more complicated. It does exactly the same thing but has option to allow us to show popups after some impressions. It also has some more built-in styles for the popup form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular Pop Up Domination plugin (paid one), for just that. I don't think we have a free one and that's why the internet is so easy to browse right now else every site would have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a search for a plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=opt+in&sort=